# Unable to sync with device

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial-python, rosserial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i've tried [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) but when i `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM1` or `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM1` (my port is ttyACM1), the result is

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1464200241.928070] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1464200241.933151] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM1 at 9600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1464200259.039163] Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

i'm sure that my rosserial is in indigo and i've tried installed again following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup). the result still the same.
though, i remember, a few weeks before, i've tried rosserial with HelloWorld and it was successful.
so i really wonder why right know i got this kind of error '-'
Help Please!!

anyway, i'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 with ROS Indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235188/unable-to-sync-with-device/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, please check your baud rate. The default baud rate in the tutorial you mentioned above is 57600. This should be set as default when you start `serial_node.py`, otherwise specify it during startup:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _baud:=57600 _port:=/dev/ttyACM0
```

---

Originally posted by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) with karma: 635 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Archana Kanwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28873/archana-kanwar/) on 2017-03-28**:
Hi, I am also facing the same problem but could not fix it even after setting the baud rate. I am working with razor 9dof IMU and was not able to make communication between Arduino and IMU. Can you please help me out in resolving this problem.

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-04**:
I have the same problem with MPU6050, can someone help me??

**Comment by [rupendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38736/rupendra/) on 2018-12-07**:
@Archana .  Did u able to solve the error for Arduino and IMU???If yes please tell the solution...Thanks